# ESS smart underscore does not work in emacs25

Tags: ess

Previously when I used the underscore key in my keyboard ESS replaced it for the assigment keys `<-`. In emacs25 that no longer happens.

I have installed the ESS package from MELPA, as well as, it's dependencies. I have the line

```
;; initialize all packages at startup
(package-initialize)
```

at the top of my `.emacs` file.

How can I replace the `_` with the `<-` when I am trying to assign a variable in R.

Comment: Inasmuch as the current stable release is Emacs 26.1, does the feature you seek work correctly with a current version of Emacs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think it is related to recent changes in ESS. Quote from here: https://ess.r-project.org/Manual/ess.html

> The variable ess-smart-S-assign-key is now deprecated and will be
>   removed in the next release. If you would like to continue using ‘_‘
>   for insterting assign in future releases, please bind
>   ess-insert-assign in ess-mode-map the normal way.

I have the following in my config to achieve exactly what you are asking

```
(define-key ess-r-mode-map "_" #'ess-insert-assign)
(define-key inferior-ess-r-mode-map "_" #'ess-insert-assign)
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick. I needed to add (require 'ess-site) to the top of the .emacs file too. I thought (package-initialize) took care of that, but nope.